# Refusal by Business Data Connectivity in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, bcs

I actually connect to external content using BCS, i can see the list in SharePoint but when i try to consume that list trough  a VS Web Part i get this error of conectivity, but this occur when i call the list from the load event 'cause when i call it from button_click event it works great, please some help will be appreciated, here is the code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(!Page.IsPostBack) loadPeoplesBDay();
        }

public void loadPeoplesBDay()
        {
            if (WebPart.List == null) return;

            SPWeb Web = SPContext.Current.Web;
            SPList List = Web.Lists[WebPart.List];

            var q = List.Items;
            var onomasticos = from persona in q.Cast<SPItem>()
                              where Convert.ToDateTime(persona["FE_NACI_TRAB"]).Month == DateTime.Now.Month
                              orderby Convert.ToDateTime(persona["FE_NACI_TRAB"]).Day ascending
                              select new { Nombre = persona["NO_TRAB"] + " " + persona["NO_APEL_PATE"] + " " + persona["NO_APEL_MATE"], Area = persona["DE_SECC"], DiaNacimiento = Convert.ToDateTime((Convert.ToDateTime(persona["FE_NACI_TRAB"]).Day + "/" + DateTime.Now.Month + "/" + DateTime.Now.Year)), Mes = persona["FE_NACI_TRAB"] };

            dlst_Onomasticos.DataSource = onomasticos;
            dlst_Onomasticos.DataBind();
        }
```